# Как сделать чтобы MiniProfiler выводился в Swagger UI (ASP.NET Core Web API)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

Есть приложение ASP.NET Core Web API. АПИ-методы выводятся в Swagger UI (выводится с помощью [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore)). Хотелось бы чтобы производитьность API-вызовов также выводились в Swagger UI с помощью MiniProfiler. Единственное, что удалось найти, так это [мануал](http://www.lambdatwist.com/webapi-profiling-with-miniprofiler-swagger/), но в нём это всё для .NET Framework, не .NET Core.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49150492/1548895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Ответ основан на [ответе с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49156781/1548895)</sup>.

Для этого вам нужно настроить файл Swagger `index.html` как объясняется в [documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#customize-indexhtml). После того, как вы настроите собственный файл HTML добавьте в него следующую строку:

```html
<script async="async" id="mini-profiler"
        src="/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js?v=4.0.0.0"
        data-version="4.0.0.0"
        data-path="/mini-profiler-resources/"
        data-current-id="865f1487-f416-4d39-87fe-723e34847577"
        data-ids=""
        data-position="left"
        data-authorized="true"
        data-max-traces="15"
        data-toggle-shortcut="Alt+P"
        data-trivial-milliseconds="2.0"
        data-ignored-duplicate-execute-types="Open,OpenAsync,Close,CloseAsync">
</script>
```

Этот скрипт является результатом вызова метода `MiniProfiler.Current.RenderIncludes()`.

Вот код методов `ConfigureServices` и `Configure` для настройки Swagger и Miniprofiler:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    });

    services.AddMiniProfiler();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseMiniProfiler();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        c.IndexStream = () => GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SOMpSwaggerNetCore.SwaggerIndex.html");
    });
    app.UseMvc();
}
```